# Will recompilation affect the running program?

Tags: compilation, python-c-extension

If I recompile a program when it is still running, will the program still be executed as the original before recompilation?

I just find some answers from [Is it safe to recompile an executable while it's running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356483/is-it-safe-to-recompile-an-executable-while-its-running), but I have a more complicated situation:

I am working on a python package with C extension;

I may recompile just a shared object in that C extension;

I will have to submit it to the queue by "qsub"...

Thanks!

Comment: In general, the answer to the question you linked to applies. But which queue are you referring to?

Comment: Depends on your cluster's setup and whether your jobs are long-running Python processes or series of short-running ones.