# How can an executable file being debugged while it changes

Tags: gdb, executable

Here is the scenario I'm asking about:

- `gdb` debugs some program executable
- programmer finds bug (good!)
- programmer fixes code and re-compiles (great!)
- programmer realizes he didn't quit gdb, so it was running all that time
- specifically, it was running **while the executable was written** and the OS (Linux) allowed it.

How come the above is possible?

Shouldn't I get some OS error message like `"file is being used by another application (gdb)"`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3356812/1983398).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't I get some OS error message like

It depends.

Suppose your rebuild command is `gcc -o foo t.c`.

This command can either `open(2)` `foo` for writing, or it can write to a temporary file `foo.$uniqsuffix` and `rename(2)` the temporary to `foo` on success, or it can `unlink(2)` `foo` and create and write to a new `foo`.

Only the first variant -- attempting to write to the *original* `foo` would fail with `ETXTBSY`.

Running `strace -fe file gcc -o foo t.c |& grep foo` on my (Ubuntu) system shows:

```
[pid 116892] stat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0750, st_size=16520, ...}) = 0
[pid 116892] lstat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0750, st_size=16520, ...}) = 0
[pid 116892] unlink("foo")              = 0
[pid 116892] openat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 116892] stat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=16520, ...}) = 0
[pid 116892] chmod("foo", 0750)         = 0
```

So on this system the linker uses `unlink` + create new file strategy, and no error is expected.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356483/is-it-safe-to-recompile-an-executable-while-its-running/3356812#3356812) for why you can continue debugging the original program even after it has been rebuilt.